# Set module on class created with `types.new_class`

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, metaprogramming

I am dynamically creating classes with `types.new_class`. Everything is going well so far. The only inconvenience is that the module the class is created is `abc`, at least when `abc.ABCMeta` is involved. Consider the following contrived example:

```py
import abc
import types

class Base(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def method(self, x):
        pass

def generate_a_class(name):
    def method(self, x):
        print(f"Method recieved {x}")

    class_body = {method.__name__: method}
    NewClass = types.new_class(
        name, bases=(Base,), exec_body=lambda ns: ns.update(class_body))

    return NewClass
```

Then we print the class generated by this method:

```py
print(generate_a_class("Implementation"))
# Prints <class 'abc.Implementation'>
```

Is there a way to define the class in the module the code is running? That would be `<class '__main__.Implementation'>` in this example.

Comment: Do you just want to assign `__module__` on the result or in `exec_body`?

Comment: @DavisHerring Now that you mention it, is actually that simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment from [Davis Herring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8586227/davis-herring) was all I needed; assigning the module directly in the class body. With that the code looks like:

```py
import abc
import types
import sys

class Base(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def method(self, x):
        pass

def generate_a_class(name, module:str = None):
    def method(self, x):
        print(f"Method recieved {x}")

    class_body = {
      "__module__": __name__ if module is None else module,
      method.__name__: method,
    }
    NewClass = types.new_class(
        name, bases=(Base,), exec_body=lambda ns: ns.update(class_body))

    return NewClass
```

And the class is associated with the correct module.

```py
print(generate_a_class("Implementation"))
# Prints <class '__main__.Implementation'>
```